# Debian package of Tomee plus

Tags: debian, tomcat

I'm looking for Debian package of Tomee plus but I have not found anything. Also, I would like to know if it is possible to download the package( on windows) then be installed on Debian or I have to download and install directly on Debian?

Answer (score 0):

You can download this package from http://apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net/tomee/tomee-1.6.0/apache-tomee-1.6.0-plus.tar.gz and install it from source..

> ```
> curl -LOC - http://apache.mirrors.lucidnetworks.net/tomee/tomee-1.6.0/apache-tomee-1.6.0-plus.tar.gz
> tar -xvf apache-tomee-1.6.0-plus.tar.gz
> cd apache-tomee-1.6.0-plus
> ```

Installing from source may be different from below instruction you can read **README** file for more information.

> ```
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```

If you don't know how to install package from source read this article:

http://www.howtogeek.com/105413/how-to-compile-and-install-from-source-on-ubuntu/

**From upper article:** Note that some applications may not use ./configure. Check the “README” or “INSTALL” file in the application’s extracted folder for more specific instructions.

Comment: Have you ever tried this before writing the answer? The installation procedure is completely different (see the README from the tarball). The download URL does not work - you get the HTML page with the links to the mirror servers instead of the tarball.